# Google Maps API v3: Group markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps with API v3. I will add many markers, now got question, is there posibility to group markers? For example, by city? I'm using a small snippet to creating sidebar with markers buttons.

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * map
 */
var mapOpts = {
  mapOpts: new google.maps.LatLng(60.28527,24.84864),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  scaleControl: true,
  scrollwheel: false
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOpts);
//  We set zoom and center later by fitBounds()



/**
 * makeMarker() ver 0.2
 * creates Marker and InfoWindow on a Map() named 'map'
 * creates sidebar row in a DIV 'sidebar'
 * saves marker to markerArray and markerBounds
 * @param options object for Marker, InfoWindow and SidebarItem
 * @author Esa 2009
 */
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markerArray = [];

function makeMarker(options){
  var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});
  pushPin.setOptions(options);
  google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, "click", function(){
    infoWindow.setOptions(options);
    infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);
    if(this.sidebarButton)this.sidebarButton.button.focus();
  });
  var idleIcon = pushPin.getIcon();
  if(options.sidebarItem){
    pushPin.sidebarButton = new SidebarItem(pushPin, options);
    pushPin.sidebarButton.addIn("sidebar");
  }
  markerBounds.extend(options.position);
  markerArray.push(pushPin);
  return pushPin;
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
  infoWindow.close();
});


/**
 * Creates a sidebar item 
 * @constructor
 * @author Esa 2009
 * @param marker
 * @param options object Supported properties: sidebarItem, sidebarItemClassName, sidebarItemWidth,
 */
function SidebarItem(marker, opts){
  var tag = opts.sidebarItemType || "button";
  var row = document.createElement(tag);
  row.innerHTML = opts.sidebarItem;
  row.className = opts.sidebarItemClassName || "sidebar_item";  
  row.style.display = "block";
  row.style.width = opts.sidebarItemWidth || "120px";
  row.onclick = function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  }
  row.onmouseover = function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseover');
  }
  row.onmouseout = function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseout');
  }
  this.button = row;
}
// adds a sidebar item to a <div>
SidebarItem.prototype.addIn = function(block){
  if(block && block.nodeType == 1)this.div = block;
  else
    this.div = document.getElementById(block)
    || document.getElementById("sidebar")
    || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  this.div.appendChild(this.button);
}
// deletes a sidebar item
SidebarItem.prototype.remove = function(){
  if(!this.div) return false;
  this.div.removeChild(this.button);
  return true;
}

/**
 * markers and info window contents
 */
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.28527,24.84864),
  title: "Vantaankoski",
  sidebarItem: "Vantaankoski",
  content: "Vantaankoski"
});   
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.27805,24.85281),
  title: "Martinlaakso",
  sidebarItem: "Martinlaakso",
  content: "Martinlaakso"
});  
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.27049,24.85366),
  title: "Louhela",
  sidebarItem: "Louhela",
  content: "Louhela"
}); 
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.26139,24.85478),
  title: "Myyrmäki",
  sidebarItem: "Myyrmäki",
  content: "Myyrmäki"
});   
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.24929,24.86128),
  title: "Malminkartano",
  sidebarItem: "Malminkartano",
  content: "Malminkartano"
});  
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.23963,24.87694),
  title: "Kannelmäki",
  sidebarItem: "Kannelmäki",
  content: "Kannelmäki"
}); 
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.23031,24.88353),
  title: "Pohjois-Haaga",
  sidebarItem: "Pohjois<br>Haaga",
  content: "Pohjois-Haaga"
});   
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.21831,24.89354),
  title: "Huopalahti",
  sidebarItem: "Huopalahti",
  content: "Huopalahti"
});   
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.20803,24.92039),
  title: "Ilmala",
  sidebarItem: "Ilmala",
  content: "Ilmala"
});    
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.19899,24.93269),
  title: "Pasila",
  sidebarItem: "Pasila",
  content: "Pasila"
});  
makeMarker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(60.17295,24.93981),
  title: "Helsinki",
  sidebarItem: "Helsinki",
  content: "Helsinki"
});    




/**
 *   fit viewport to markers
 */
map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
```

Answer (score 10):

[Here's the v3 version](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries):

> #### Marker Clusterer
>
> ...The library creates and manages per-zoom-level clusters for large amounts of markers. This is a V3 implementation of the V2 MarkerClusterer.
>
> Browse [Released Versions](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/) or [Development Versions](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/)...

Answer (score 9):

Better yet, use MarkerClustererPlus. Many enhancements and it incorporates plenty of bug fixes for problems found in the original MarkerClusterer.

Answer (score 7):

See this: [Introduction to Marker Clustering With Google Maps](http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/11/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps) and MarkerClusterer here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/.

Answer (score 2):

You should use markerclusterer (http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html). A working example:

```
function drop() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markere.length; i++) {
    //setTimeout(function() {//for maps with few markers works great to add them with delay
    addMarker();
    //}, i * 200);
  }

  //group markers; page loads a lot faster when you have many markers
  var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);//group with markerclusterer (don't forget to include the js file)

  //make sure they fit screen
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
    bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds); 
}


function addMarker() {
    /*before pushing we set some properties */
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markere[i],
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        flat: false,
        icon: "./wp-content/themes/clear/images/obiectiv.png",
        title: denumire[i]
    })
    /*set infowindow*/
    var content = "<p><strong>"+denumire[i]+"</strong></p>";
    var catStr = '';
    var nrCat = categorii[i].length;
    for (var j = 0; j < nrCat; j++) {
        catStr += categorii[i][j];
    }
    content+= "<p>"+catStr+"</p>";
    nrCatStr = "";
    if (nrCat==1) nrCatStr = "categorie"
    else if (nrCat>1) nrCatStr = "categorii";
    content+= "<p>"+nrCat+" "+nrCatStr+"</p>";        
    /* //I don't use mouseover/mouseout
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        this.infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        this.infowindow.close(map, this);
    });*/
    //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
    infowindow = null;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        if (infowindow) {
            infowindow.close();
        }
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
            stopBounce(markers);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, this);

        toggleBounce(this);
    });

    markers.push(marker);
    i++;
}/**/


drop();//drop the markers

function toggleBounce(obj) {
    if (obj.getAnimation() != null) {
        obj.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        stopBounce(markers);//stop bouncing markers
        obj.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}

function stopBounce(markers){
    for (var k = 0; k < markers.length; k++) {
        if (markers[k].getAnimation() != null) { markers[k].setAnimation(null); }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet below may do the job for you.

```
function codeAddress() {
 var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            if(!map)    {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);}

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            bounds.extend(marker.position);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover',   ( function(marker) {
            return function() {
               var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
              //  alert("hi");
                var content = '<div class="map-content"><h3>' + address + '</h3> </div>';
              infowindow.setContent(content);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker));
        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google code has been deprecated as per

http://google-opensource.blogspot.com.es/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html

So all libraries mentioned in previous answers migrated to GitHub. You can find them at

https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library